# C++ timezone offset to parsed time

Tags: c++, date, parsing, c++-chrono

I have some code that uses [Howard Hinnant's date Library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) to parse microsecond enabled timestamps:

```
    std::string time_test = "13:45:04.747334";
    std::istringstream input(time_test);
    std::chrono::microseconds current_time;

    input >> date::parse("%T", current_time);
```

This yields the microseconds since midnight but it is assumed that the microseconds.

Now I need to add it to the microseconds since epoch for today's local midnight but the library makes the localtime assuming that `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` provides time in UTC.

How do get time since epoch calculated as local time?

Comment: Added the chrono tag because certain individuals who can give a real crackerjack answer, such as Mr. Hinnant, are known to monitor the tag.

Comment: Ok, you got my ears burning. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with local time you will need to [install the `"date/tz.h"` library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).  This involves compiling one source file:  tz.cpp and either allowing an automatic downloading the IANA timezone database, manually installing it yourself, or using your OS's copy (if available).

The easiest way to get the current local time is to combine `system_clock::now()` with `current_zone()` in an object called `zoned_time`:

```
zoned_time zt{current_zone(), system_clock::now()};
```

`current_zone()` returns a `time_zone const*` to a time zone representing your computer's currently set local time zone.  From `zoned_time` you can get your local time:

```
auto local_tp = zt.get_local_time();
```

`local_tp` is a `chrono::time_point`, but offset from `system_clock::time_point` by your time zone's current UTC offset.  Then you can work with `local_tp` just like you might work with `system_clock::time_point`.  For example, to get the local time of day:

```
auto tod = local_tp - floor<days>(local_tp);
```

`tod` is just a `chrono::duration` measuring the time since the local midnight.

Or if you have such a duration, such as the `current_time` you parsed in in your question, you could add that to the local midnight:

```
auto tp = floor<days>(local_tp) + current_time;
```

Here, `tp` would have the type `local_time<microseconds>`.  And `local_time<duration>` is just a type-alias for `chrono::time_point<local_t, duration>`.

> How do get time since epoch calculated as local time?

This is a somewhat ambiguous question so I have not addressed it directly.  However I'd be happy to try if you can clarify the question.  The epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, and the time duration since that instant is independent of any time zone.

To further elaborate, given the current local time (`current_time`) and assuming we know the local date (e.g. 2020-12-16), we can form a `zoned_time` that encapsulates both the local time and the UTC equivalent:

```
string time_test = "19:45:04.747334";
istringstream input(time_test);
chrono::microseconds current_time;

input >> date::parse("%T", current_time);

local_days today{2020_y/12/16};
zoned_time zt{current_zone(), today + current_time};
cout << format("%F %T %Z\n", zt);
cout << format("%F %T %Z\n", zt.get_sys_time());
```

Output:

```
2020-12-16 19:45:04.747334 EST
2020-12-17 00:45:04.747334 UTC
```

Comment: What I meant was: `2020-12-16 19:00:00 EST` is `2020-12-17 00:00:00 UTC` so if I only have the timestamp portion of the string: `2020-12-16 19:00:00` I need to make the code assume that the timezone is what is locally set on my machine or otherwise specified during parsing so that (nano, micro, milli)seconds since epoch is calculated correctly with the tz offset included.

Comment: Does adding 19:00:00 to the local midnight of 2020-12-16 address your problem?